# Guava's FluentIterable thread-safe

Tags: java, thread-safety, guava, immutability

`FluentIterable` has only one final field -- the delegate `Iterable`.

So it seems it's thread-safe as long as the internal `Iterable` instance is thread-safe, but I can't find it stated anywhere in the docs. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FluentIterable` is a stateless view on another `Iterable` therefore (as you said) it does not impose thread unsafety.